# Sudden error in working script Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below code was working for the last two years without any problem.
Suddenly there is an error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
main    @ Code.gs:45

at line : var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

When I logged by :   Logger.log(response.getContentText())

Logging output too large. Truncating output. <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src none 'self' https://3commas.io https://app.3commas.io; img-src 'self' blob: data: https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/ https://*.g.doubleclick.net https://*.doubleclick.net https://*.ytimg.com *.cloudflareaccess.com https://*.quora.com https://*.outbrain.com https://*.reddit.com https://bat.bing.com https://3commasio-public.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com https://secure.gravatar.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://static.intercomassets.com https://uploads.intercomusercontent.com https://messenger-apps.intercom.io https://*.intercomcdn.com ............

Not able to find any changes they made to the API

[https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs](https://API%20Document)

```
function fetch() {
  var key = '';
  var secret = '';
  var baseUrl = "https://3commas.io"; // Modified
  var endPoint = "/public/api/ver1/accounts";
  var pointParams = "?limit=10&offset=&account_id=&scope=&type="; // or "?limit=10"
  var queryString = endPoint + pointParams; // Modified
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(queryString, secret); // Added
  signature = signature.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");  // Added
  var hparams = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'APIKEY': key,
                'Signature': signature},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + queryString , hparams);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText())
  var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var headers = Object.keys(object[0]);
  var values = object.map(function(e) {return headers.map(function(f) {return e[f]})});
  values.unshift(headers);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
//
```

Comment: About `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`, I think that the reason for your current issue is due to that `response.getContentText()` is invalid JSON data. About `Not able to find any changes they made to the API`, I'm not sure about the API you want to use. I apologize for my poor skill. But, I think that it is required to confirm the current specification of the API. So, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs

Comment: Thank you for replying. As one more question, what is your current error message from the API? I would like to confirm whether your current request is a valid request to the API. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't confirm it. I apologize for this.

Comment: By the way, when I saw your provided document, unfortunately, I couldn't find the document of the endpoint `/public/api/ver1/accounts` you want to use. I apologize for this. Where can I see it?

Comment: https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs/blob/master/3commas_openapidoc.yml

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand the method of the API you want to use. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.